# Diffrientiation in outputs depending on the ommition of curly braces in for loops (c++)

Tags: c++, curly-braces, curly-brackets

I have been going through the c++ primer book as suggested by a reference guide on this site and I noticed the author omits curly braces for the for loop.I checked other websites and the braces are supposed to be put in usually. There is a different output when putting the curly braces and omitting it.The code is below

```
int sum = 0;
for (int val = 1; val <= 10; ++val)
    sum += val;  
    std::cout << "Sum of 1 to 10 inclusive is " << sum << std::endl;

// This pair of code prints the std::cout once
for (int val = 50; val <=100;++val)
    sum += val;
    std::cout << "Sum of 50 to 100 inclusive is " << sum << std::endl;

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
for (int val = 1; val <= 10; ++val) {
    sum += val;  
    std::cout << "Sum of 1 to 10 inclusive is " << sum << std::endl;
}

// This pair of code prints the std::cout multiple times
for (int val = 50; val <=100;++val) {
    sum += val;
    std::cout << "Sum of 50 to 100 inclusive is " << sum << std::endl;
}
```

I would appreciate if anyone could explain the difference in outputs. Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"... and I noticed the author omits curly braces for the for loop."_ Throw that book into your bin. Immediately.

Comment: The best advice is to **always** use curly braces with your for/while/if statements.  Omitting braces is legacy syntax that should be avoided, IMO.  See also https://www.google.com/search?q=heartbleed

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Lol I already stopped using another book for 'promoting bad practices'.

Comment: @RyanBemrose Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With curly braces everything in the braces get executed by the for loop

```
for (...;...;...)
{
     // I get executed in the for loop!
     // I get executed in the for loop too!
}
// I don't get executed in the for loop!
```

However without curly braces it only executes the statement directly after it:

```
for (...;...;...)
     // I get executed in the for loop!
// I don't get executed in the for loop!
// I don't get executed in the for loop either!
```

Comment: Also note: This happens regardless of whitespace - it's the next statement, not the next line. Indentation is only there to make it easier for programmers to read the program.

Comment: It's very important to distinguish between the next statement and the next line!

Comment: Thanks these comments helped me understand it better!

Comment: oops I think I use the term statement and line interchangeably :p should probably stop that.

Answer (score 3):

The for statement in particularly is defined the following way

```
for ( for-init-statement conditionopt; expressionopt) statement
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^
```

where the statement can be any statement including the compound statement

```
compound-statement:
    { statement-seqopt}
```

Thus in this example of a for statement

```
for (int val = 1; val <= 10; ++val)
sum += val;
```

the statement is

```
sum += val;
```

While in this example of a for statement

```
for (int val = 1; val <= 10; ++val) {
sum += val;  
std::cout << "Sum of 1 to 10 inclusive is " << sum << std::endl;
}
```

the statement is

```
{
sum += val;  
std::cout << "Sum of 1 to 10 inclusive is " << sum << std::endl;
}
```